How does chromium apk load external lib-ffmpeg?
Is there a way to make chromium APks that do not contain libffmpeg and only load external libffmpeg at runtime?
I tried unpacking, unpacking, and signing the TrichromeLibrary.apk with apktool, but the trichromelibrary.apk didn't install to the board.
